# Is a PlanningSceneDiff without CollisionObject shapes valid?

Tags: ros, collision-object, environment-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm wondering how far the concept of a PlanningSceneDiff goes when it is applied.

As an explicit example: If there is some CollisionObject published to the environment server and added with id, pose, shape, etc. and now I construct a PlanningSceneDiff that contains a CollisionObject, where only id and pose(s) are set, what should happen?

Will this update the CollisionObject with the same id and the new poses + the originally added shapes or will it update the CollisionObject with the new poses and empty shapes?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38637/is-a-planningscenediff-without-collisionobject-shapes-valid?/) by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31395 on 2012-07-12

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Or the third option would be that it may segfault.  Looking at the code if there is an existing object of a given id and another in the diff the object in the diff will overwrite the previous object.  Thus you should make sure that the diff contains a one-to-one relationship between shapes and poses.

---

Originally posted by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) with karma: 2031 on 2012-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1